# Motion remap to select function doesn't work with v

Tags: vimscript, cursor-motions, normal-mode, cursor

I want to add a motion:

```
:onoremap <silent> f( :<C-U>normal! f)vF(b<CR>
```

If I have this line, where the asterisk is my current position:

```
int a = fo*o(4, 5, 99);
```

I want to type <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> and select `foo(4, 5, 99)`. Later on I want to add the equivalents for `[`, `{`, and `<`.

However the above sadly doesn't work. This is an altered version of something I found under `:help omap-info`.

EDIT: Actually, it work with <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd>, but not with <kbd>v</kbd>. Why is that?

Comment: You want to select a word and arguments next to it, right? Are you okay with some other mappings then?

Comment: Well, yes, show me.

Comment: How about `:nmap \sf bvf(f)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Operator pending mode` has to be used only when waiting for a motion. You have used `f`, which waits for a character and moves there. Since you have given both `f` and `(` together, `f` has got a character to find and move to. Hence, there isn't any operator 'pending'!

So, you can map in normal mode itself, like

```
 :noremap <silent> f( :<C-U>normal! f)vF(b<CR>
```

(This works in my vim.)

Or, you can use a simple mapping like

```
 :nmap \sf bvf(f)
```

(s - select, f - function)

**EDIT:** You can put `[`,`{`,`<`  instead of `(` in the above mappings to use with `[`,`{`,`<`.

You can create your own text objects as well as use plugins like easy motions for that.

Answer (score 3):

You (also) need to address the `visual` mode map (`onoremap` doesn't do that):

```
:xnoremap <silent> f( :<C-U>normal! f)vF(b<CR>
```

See also: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects
(where the `omap` is made based on the `vnoremap`).

Answer (score 2):

`:onoremap <silent> f( :<C-U>normal! f)vF(b<CR>`

works well for

`int a = foo(4, 5, 99);`

but if you are using `fo*o` you need you `b` three times

BTW, you can use

`:onoremap <silent> f( :<C-U>normal! f)vF(F l<cr>`

Comment: * in f*oo is the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished what I wanted to do initially and it works quite nicely.
I didn't use `(`, `{` and etc. because I made it behave similiar to [tpope's vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

```
function s:StatementOperator(opennext, closenext)
    let current_col = col(".")
    execute 'normal! m"f' . a:closenext
    let last_col = col(".")
    execute 'normal! vF' . a:opennext . 'b'
    let first_col = col(".")

    if first_col > current_col || current_col > last_col
        normal! v`"
    endif
endfunction

onoremap <silent> pb :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('(',')')<cr>
onoremap <silent> pB :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('{','}')<cr>
onoremap <silent> pr :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('[',']')<cr>
onoremap <silent> pa :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('<','>')<cr>
vnoremap <silent> pb :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('(',')')<cr>
vnoremap <silent> pB :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('{','}')<cr>
vnoremap <silent> pr :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('[',']')<cr>
vnoremap <silent> pa :<c-u>call <sid>StatementOperator('<','>')<cr>
```